# Magento 2: Is there any option to use MYSQL search engine for magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I need to use the MYSQL search engine instead of Elasticsearch in Magento 2.4 so is there any way of plugin for that?

Thanks.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/330162/34579  - this may help you upon your system stack  and you can then use this to switch to mysql legacy  - https://github.com/swissup/module-search-mysql-legacy

Answer (score 1):

As @sandip already mentioned in the comment, there might be a way to overwrite the native behavior and use MySQL as search engine in Magento 2.4.2 **BUT I wouldn't recommend that**. Why? Because there is no guarantee that all functionalities are covered properly AND there is no guarantee that the extensions will keep up with the Magento upgrades or quality patches, which means **you will either delay the upgrades OR you will face disruptions in your search related functionalities.**